# Why are path variable keys being read as values in my Django application?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to build an api. This is my first time working with DRF, but have experience working with Laravel/NestJs so the concept of routing isn't too unfamiliar.

In my DRF application, my url config looks something like this:

```
// urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/accounts/<str:account_number>/', accounts.AccountsViewSet.as_view()),

    url('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

In Postman, I am sending a `GET` request to the following url:

```
{{my_host}}/api/v1/accounts/:account_number/
```

My view looks like this:

```
// view.py

def get(self, request, account_number=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print(account_number)

        if account_number is not None:
            print('account_number was provided')
        else:
            print('account_number not provided')
```

When sending a `GET` request to my endpoint, I can provide a value for `account_number` key. Let's say I use `ABC123` as the key value. Given the above view, the first print statement returns `ABC123`.

I will also get into the first `if` block and see the message `account_number was provided` All is well!

However, if I do *not* provide an account number (I leave the path variable value empty) I am getting the path variable itself in my logging. For example:

```
// view.py

def get(self, request, account_number=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print(account_number) // :account_number

        if account_number is not None:
            print('account_number was provided'). <!-- still getting here
        else:
            print('account_number not provided')
```

As you can see, I am getting the variable. I would expect to be getting an empty string `''` not the variable name (key) `:account_number`.

I have tried setting the values to check for empty string, or `null` (also a string) but since the `:account_number` key is getting passed in...I'm not sure what else to try.

How can I check if `:account_number` is empty (was not provided) in my view? Is this something unique to DRF? I am able to do these checks quite easily with Laravel and/or NestJs.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I think that's something to do with postman, if you check cURL generated for request with filled :account_number parameter and without you can see that when Value for this path variable is not specified it defaults to it's key value

Comment: Ah, I can see that now...



`curl --location 'http://host.com/api/v1/accounts/AAA/'`
And:

`curl --location 'http://host.com/api/v1/accounts/:account_number/'`

Comment: It's interesting, if I set the path variable to an environment variable, I get the following: `curl --location 'http://host.com/api/v1/accounts//'`

This results in a 404 much like @Sumithran mentions.

Comment: @Damon did my solution worked for you?

Comment: @Sumithran, I ended up setting the value(s) of my path variables as environment variables. So, my url looked like http://host.com/api/v1/accounts/{{account_number}}/

Thank you very much for your suggestion - I appreciate your time!